# If attr_accessor includes an element, eg. ':name', is there any need for the 'name=' method?

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

Preface: I do understand the standard definition for attr_accessor and know that attr_accessor stands for two instance methods-a setter and a writer, and attr_accessor allows instances variables to be accessible throughout the class.

But now and then I see an element included in attr_accessor AND is defined as a method.

So my question is: Why does that happen? Is it just bad code I saw?

Pseudo/example code:

```
class Such_n_such
    attr_accessor :name, :color  
            #code omitted
       def color=(color)
         (some code)
       end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aren't setter and writer the same thing?

Comment: I don't think so--setter sets the value, period, as in "def name @name = name", and writer allows values to be re-set, as in "def name=(name)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue that you should not use `attr_accessor` and then override the setter.

I prefer using `attr_reader` with custom setter methods:

```
attr_accessor :name
attr_reader :color  

def color=(color)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `attr_accessor` adds in the setter and getter method for that attribute and no it is not a bad practice if you need a custom setter. Say you want a setter for color like your example. You want to take in the fact that color could be a number, string, etc...

Comment: Don't the two conflict then? That is: Does attr_accessor get overridden by the custom setter?

Comment: No, it doesn't get overridden. It gets overwritten. There is no inheritance here, thus no overriding.